# Are there any effects to reading an Elder Scroll?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got an Elder Scroll while doing the quest "Elder Knowledge", and I wanted to know if there are any effects to reading an Elder Scroll?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you will be stunned and blinded for a few seconds upon reading it. If you read it at the Throat of the World, however, something interesting will happen.

Comment: Also, though this is not directly relevant to the question, you can sell the scroll to a certain orc librarian at the College of Winterhold after the interesting thing has happened.

Comment: And if you have Dawnguard, you can sell it to the moth priest and he'll give you more gold than the orc at the College Library.