# What happens if I read the Elder Scrolls over and over again?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I already know the [interesting thing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51084/are-there-any-effects-to-reading-an-elder-scroll) that happens when you read the Scroll on the highest of Skyrim's mountains, and I already know what happens when you read a Elder Scroll anywhere else.

I also read from in-game sources that reading the Scrolls over and over again will make you go blind forever. Does this actually happen in the game or are we just Aedra who can read the Scroll over and over again with only temporary blindness?

Comment: I think it would be great if you would actually be able to turn blind (at least temporarily) by reading the Elder Scrolls too often! Don't know about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going blind from reading the scrolls only happens in the lore of the game (and to one NPC if you have the Dawnguard expansion).

You can try to read an Elder Scroll however many times as you like, but your character in Skyrim will not be affected.